# Sharing links in phonegap app w/o java plugins

Tags: javascript, cordova, sharing

Is there any reliable way to share links in an iphone and android compatible phonegap application without the need for plugins? (We are building via phonegap-build, which doesn't allow you to include any java plugins)

Have tried with iframes, but they behave oddly and inconsistently, or in the case of the facebook one, does not even seem to load.

```
<iframe src="http://mobile.twitter.com/?status={{url}}" frameborder="0"></iframe>

<iframe src="https://m.facebook.com/sharer.php?u={{url}}" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the childbrowser(InAppBrowser for cordova 2.3) plugin for sharing those links, basically childbrowser allows you to launch browser dialog from inside your application and you have full control on it , this plugin is compatible with the phonegap build, so you can use it without losing the ability to use the official phonegap build.

Also use of iframes is not recommeneded for android, because iframes have some weird behaviour in mobile browsers(specially in android), I personally had one instance where page was not scrollng in android gingerbread devices when an iframe was hidden :P